# Why SCM weights *should* sum to 1?

Tags: optimization, econometrics, causality, constrained-regression, constrained-optimization

When we use [synthetic controls](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jasa.2009.ap08746), we consider $j=2, \dots, J+1$ units across $t \in \{T_{-} \ldots T_0 \ldots T_{+}\} \in \mathbb{Z}$ pre/post event-time periods. Abadie et. al. make the point that to prevent extrapolation, the weights used in this equation
$$
 \|X_1-X_0W \|= \sqrt{\left(X_1-X_0W\right)^\prime V-\left(X_1-X_0W\right)}
$$
are chosen via this optimization problem
$$
\text{argmin} \sum_{j=1}^k v_j \bigg(X_{1j} - \sum_{j=2}^{J+1}w_jX_{jm} \bigg)^2 \text{s.t.} \sum_{j}^{J}w_{j}=1 \: \text{and}  \: w_{j} \geq 0 
$$
Why is the adding up constraint and the positivity constraint useful in preventing extrapolation?

Could anyone familiar with the mathematics of constrained optimization talk about *why* these two specific conditions prevent extrapolation? Why can't the weights add up to 1.9, or why can't we have negative weights and prevent extrapolation? I understand why we don't (usually) want extrapolation, but why do these *specific* constraints make extrapolation impossible?

Comment: Take a look at [p. 395](https://economics.mit.edu/files/17847#page=5) and Section of Abadie's 2021 JEL paper, especially the papers cited in footnote 5 and King and Zeng (2006).

Comment: That should read "Section 4".

Comment: Thanks so much Dimitriy. I must read this paper again for a third time, I learn something new each time I read it. @dimitriy